# AppEngine: Make page inaccessible when typed in

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-app-engine

I am doing the following with Google App Engine:

User clicks an "email me" button in the footer, which loads an email form into a popup overlay using the following code:

```
$('#lightbox-overlay').load('/email #content')
```

"/email" is set in the dispatcher to Email.index, which is a standard view which outputs a django form:

```
import os
import webapp2
import util
from models import EmailForm
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class index(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        html = "email.html"
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates', html)
        self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
        self.response.write(template.render(path, {'form': EmailForm()}))
```

What I would like to know: can I make it impossible for the user to access "/email" except by this jQuery request? It's pointless for the user to be able to access the form outside of the popup that I am loading it into.

Comment: It's not possible but why would you want to do it anyway? What if a search engine web crawler wants to view the /email form for example.

Comment: Like I said: It's pointless for the user to be able to access the form outside of the popup that I am loading it into. And I don't mind if a webcrawler misses out on the email me form.

Comment: A user won't access /email unless they are a hacker or unless you link to it. I would just not link to it anywhere on your site.

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible as you describe. However you could generate a different token and pass it on the url as in /email?token=xxx and validate xxx. If the user tries to enter to just /email or a url with an old token you make it fail.

Answer (score 0):

jquery AJAX requests are usually sent with an additional header:

```
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

You can try to detect this header and fail if the header is not there.  Something like:

```
class index(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        if self.request.headers.get("x_requested_with") == "XMLHttpRequest":
            # return email form
        else:
            # return failure.
```

Note that this would just be a cosmetic measure, it's not hackproof.  A hacker can easily fake the header.